# Robots text, wordpress - block directory

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

In my robots.txt i have this:

```
Disallow: /lo
```

lo is a directory with a script i want blocked.

Problem is that "Disallow: /lo" blocks a post of mine:

/lonely-cars-etc/

How shall i block lo directory corectly?

Please, take a look at my robots.txt. Maybe there are other problems i don't know about.

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /bin
Disallow: /cgi
Disallow: /cron
Disallow: /lo/
Disallow: /stats
Disallow: /portfolio.html

Disallow: /wp-admin
Disallow: /wp-includes
Disallow: /wp-login.php
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins
Disallow: /wp-content/themes
Disallow: /wp-content/cache

Allow: /wp-content/uploads
Allow: /wp-content/blogs.dir

Disallow: /author
Disallow: /tag
Disallow: /archives
Disallow: /2010/*
Disallow: /2011/*
Disallow: /2012/*
Disallow: /about/

Disallow: /trackback
Disallow: */trackback 
Disallow: /comments
Disallow: */comments
Disallow: /feed
Disallow: */feed
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*.js$
Disallow: /*.inc$
Disallow: /*.css$
Disallow: /*.gz$
Disallow: /*.wmv$
Disallow: /*.cgi$
Disallow: /*.xhtml$
Disallow: /*.xlsx $
Disallow: /*.doc$
Disallow: /*.pdf$
Disallow: /*.zip$

# Google Image
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:
Allow: /*
```

P.S.
On webmastertools i get this:
Is this right?

http://www.site.com/wordpress-post/
Allowed
Detected as a directory; specific files may have different restrictions

Not sure it's write for a wordpress page to be detected as a directory! Any opinions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use /lo/ instead of just /lo

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can suggest you is to manually allow the post:

```
Allow: /lonely-cars-etc/
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How about Disallow: /lo/ instead of Disallow /lo

Answer (score 0):

Googlebot supports using $ to specify end of line, so you should be able to use the following:

```
Disallow: /lo$
```